# Ruby on Rails Error - already activated xxxxx, but your Gemfile requires yyyyy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am just getting started on RoR and I encounter errors like - "already activated xxxxx, but your Gemfile requires yyyyy", etc. I tried searching for information to better understand the RoR gem, plug-ins loading process, but couldn't find any. Could somebody point to good resources/book which can help understand RoR mechanics.

p.s.: I am a 10+ years .Net guy making a move to RoR, interested in learning the RoR mechanics instead of just how-tos.

Comment: What exact command are you running?

Comment: You did not specify a version for one of your gems in your Gemfile, so running `bundle install` or `bundle update` locked the gem (in your Gemfile.lock file) to the current version of the gem on your system.  Since then you updated the gem on your system to a newer version, so when Rails starts up it loads the newer version which does not match the version specified in Gemfile.lock.  This isn't a big deal, just run `bundle update` again so that Gemfile.lock reflects the updated gems.

Comment: Also, good luck with the move from .NET.  I came from a predominantly .NET background to Rails, too.  It takes a bit of adjustment, but it's worth it.  Be glad that you have experience from both platforms that you can benefit from.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Your explanation is very helpful. I started my first RoR hobby project(day job is on .Net) and I am trying to do XML-Rpc, I tried various gems, so possibly I messed up the Gemfile.lock. bundle exec resolved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running `bundle install` or `bundle update`... it sounds like your Gemfile has conflicting information than what your actual environment has.

If that doesn't help, use `bundle exec <actual command here>`.

Comment: In fact, when working in a project that uses bundler, it's best to get in the habit of simply typing `bundle exec ` in front of any ruby command, or any command that will result in ruby code being run.  This will prevent (for instance) `rake` from loading a newer version of a gem prior to invoking the ruby code that explicitly tries to work with bundled gems.

Comment: Unless you're using `rvm >= 1.6.18`, which ties in with bundler and removes that need ;)

Comment: Extremly sorry for the late reply(I was swamped by my .Net day job). I was getting this error while trying to run rake db:migrate command. I had tried bundle install/update, but it didn't help. I tried executing rake through bundle exec and it worked. By the way, I am using rvm 1.6.20. Thank you for the inputs.